# C addressing method

Tags: c, char, addressing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define can 100
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
 void hesaplacumle(int *sayi,char dizi[can])
 {
    *sayi=strlen(dizi);
    printf("Karakter dizimin boyu: %d\n",*sayi);
    
 }
 void ortakhesap(int *ortak,char dizi1[can])
 {
     *ortak=0;
 int i=0;
  int konum=0;
  int num1[26]={0};
  int num2[26]={0};
  while(dizi1[i])
  {
    if(dizi1[i]==32)
      {
        break;
      }
    else if(dizi1[i]>96 && dizi1[i]<123)
    {
        konum=dizi1[i]-'a';
        num1[konum]++;
    }
    i++;
  }
   i+=1;
    while(dizi1[i])
  {
    
    if(dizi1[i]>96 && dizi1[i]<123)
    {
        konum=dizi1[i]-'a';
        num2[konum]++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
     
     
    i++;
  }

 
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
    if(num1[i]!=0 && num2[i]!=0)
    {
        *ortak++;
    }
    }
    printf("2 kelimenin ortak harf sayisi: %d",*ortak);
 }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int ortak;
  char dizi[100];
  char dizi1[100];
  int sayi;
  printf("\nLutfen bir cumle giriniz: \n");
  gets(dizi);
  hesaplacumle(&sayi,dizi);
  
  printf("\nLutfen iki kelime giriniz: \n\n");
  gets(dizi1);
  
  
  ortakhesap(&ortak,dizi1);
 
  
    
}
```

hesaplacumle(&sayi,dizi);  I was expecting exactly same ouput from this function it is OK.However,
ortakhesap(&ortak,dizi1); when I try this one without using function it works properly.On the other hand, when I try it using a function it prodcues same ridiculous outputs which I do not understand.Here my question is what I am missing?Main idea is using addressing method.Thanks for your helps.Due my respects.

hesaplacumle(&sayi,dizi) this one calculates long of the sentences.
ortakhesap(&ortak,dizi1); this one calculates common character number between two word.
[image: True and wrong output]

Comment: OT: Never ***ever*** use the `gets` function! It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that is has even been removed from the C language. Any resource, book, tutorial or class that teaches it should be thrown away.

Comment: As for your problem, can you please narrow it down, do we need all that code for it? Is it really a [mre]? And please try to give your functions and variables English names, and try to write English output. It will make it much easier for us to know what's going on.

Comment: Oh and please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If e.g. `dizi1[i]>96 && dizi1[i]<123` is supposed to check for ASCII-encoded lower-case letters, then use the standard [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower) function instead. Besides making your code cleaner and easier to read, it will also handle non-ASCII encodings. And instead of `dizi1[i]==32` to check for space, check for an actual space: `dizi1[i]==' '`.

Comment: Your code would be *much* easier to read if it consistently used any of the common indentation schemes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with function `ortakhesap()` is here:

> ```
>         *ortak++;
> ```

You intend to increment the `int` to which `ortak` points, but postfix `++` has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator, so you are instead incrementing the pointer itself, then dereferencing it and discarding the value.  You could achieve what you intended by inserting parentheses ...

```
        (*ortak)++;
```

... or by using plussignment instead of the increment operator ...

```
        *ortak += 1;
```

. Better, however, would be either to use the function's return value instead of an out parameter, or at least to use a local variable to accumulate the count, and set `*ortak` only once, at the end.